# Connecting to Flask using websockets hosted on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, websocket, flask-sockets

I'm trying to make a turn-based game in Godot that is hosted on an external server to prevent cheating. Websockets seem to be the best solution and Heroku apparently supports websockets. I'm trying to use [flask-sockets](https://github.com/heroku-python/flask-sockets) to accomplish this but cannot get anything to work. I keep getting this error in my Heroku logs:

```
2022-08-10T01:13:42.934964+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-08-10T01:13:42.934997+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 999, in handle_one_response
2022-08-10T01:13:42.934998+00:00 app[web.1]: self.run_application()
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935002+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geventwebsocket/handler.py", line 75, in run_application
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935002+00:00 app[web.1]: self.run_websocket()
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935004+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geventwebsocket/handler.py", line 52, in run_websocket
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935005+00:00 app[web.1]: list(self.application(self.environ, lambda s, h, e=None: []))
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935017+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935018+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935029+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sockets.py", line 40, in __call__
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935029+00:00 app[web.1]: handler, values = adapter.match()
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935039+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/routing/map.py", line 622, in match
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935040+00:00 app[web.1]: raise WebsocketMismatch() from None
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935067+00:00 app[web.1]: werkzeug.routing.exceptions.WebsocketMismatch: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
2022-08-10T01:13:42.935181+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-08-10T01:13:42Z {'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.1.31.248', 'REMOTE_PORT': '12800', 'HTTP_HOST': 'reversertesterheroku.herokuapp.com', (hidden keys: 33)} failed with WebsocketMismatch
```

Here is my Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sockets import Sockets

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/reverse')
def echo_socket(ws):
    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        ws.send(message[::-1])

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Every websocket testing method I use does not work so I am almost 100% certain something is wrong on the server side.

[This is all of my Heroku files](https://github.com/h1d34uz3hunt3r/herokuwebsockettesting) if everything above isn't enough. PLEASE help me find a solution or a working alternative.

Comment: The `flask-sockets` module appears to be unmaintained: the [original repository](https://github.com/heroku-python/flask-sockets) has been archived, and the [fork linked from pypi](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets) had the last release in 2016. I think you're going to need to look for an alternative solution.

Comment: @larsks Thanks, that's really unfortunate as the official [Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-websockets) uses this library.

Comment: It looks like there is a mechanism for providing feedback at the bottom of that page. Probably worth mentioning it to them.